# sumar inputs con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

tengo un formulario en html y necesito que los inputs se vayan sumando cuando se va agregando valor a ellos (pierda el focus), lo he intentado con una clase de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function calcular_total() {

    var importe_total = 0
    $('.amt').keyup(function (){
        $(".amt").each(
            function(index, value) {
                importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
                console.log(importe_total);
            }
        );  
    });
    $("#inputTotal").val(importe_total);
}
```

la funcion es llamada en el documen ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    calcular_total();

});
```

html

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%;">Costos Servicios</td>
            <td style="width:25%;"><input type="text" id="inputCostosServicios" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right"/></td>
            <td style="width:25%;">Costo Logistica</td>
            <td style="width:25%;"><input type="text" id="inputCostoLogistica" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%;">Costo Infraestructura</td>
            <td style="width:25%;"><input type="text" id="inputCostoInfraestructura" class="solo-numero amt"  style="width:70% !important; text-align:right"/></td>
            <td style="width:25%;">Costo  Contingencia</td>
            <td style="width:25%;"><input type="text" id="inputCostoContingencia" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%;">Costo Licencias</td>
            <td style="width:25%;"><input type="text" id="inputCostoLicencias" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right"/></td>
            <td style="width:25%;">Otros Costos</td>
            <td style="width:25%;"><input type="text" id="inputOtrosCostos1" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><div style="text-align:right; margin-right:7%;"><label style="margin-right:8px;">Total</label><input type="text" id="inputTotal" class="solo-numero" style="width:18% !important; margin-right:-2px; text-align:right"/></div></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: calcular_total() no es necesaria por que no se ejecuta al momento de crearla en el ready, el código de tu función debe ir en el ready

Comment: @ReneLimon lo he sacado y he puesto en el document ready y no ha funcionado, continua sin hacer nada

Comment: añade tambien el codigo html por favor

Comment: @ReneLimon ya agregue el html :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algunos temas importantes:

- `$("#inputTotal").val(importe_total);` estaba fuera de la función `keyup` al igual que `importe_total`
- los input deben tener un valor por defecto de cero(para evitar errores).
- se debe validar que los dígitos introducidos sean números (verificar [números validos](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)).

```js
$('.amt').keyup(function() {
var importe_total = 0
  $(".amt").each(
    function(index, value) {
      if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
      importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
      //console.log(importe_total);
      }
    }
  );
      $("#inputTotal").val(importe_total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:25%;">Costos Servicios</td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <input type="text" id="inputCostosServicios" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;">Costo Logistica</td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <input type="text" id="inputCostoLogistica" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:25%;">Costo Infraestructura</td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <input type="text" id="inputCostoInfraestructura" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;">Costo Contingencia</td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <input type="text" id="inputCostoContingencia" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:25%;">Costo Licencias</td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <input type="text" id="inputCostoLicencias" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;">Otros Costos</td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <input type="text" id="inputOtrosCostos1" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div style="text-align:right; margin-right:7%;">
        <label style="margin-right:8px;">Total</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputTotal" class="solo-numero" style="width:18% !important; margin-right:-2px; text-align:right" />
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, tu estas llamando a una funcion `calcular_total()`, que dentro esta utilizando una funcion de pulso `.keyup()` por lo tanto jamas va a funcionar.

Puedes probar con esto `onChange()` detecta cualquier cambio en tu input, cuando el usuario siga escribiendo inmediatamente se van a ver los cambios en el input total. :

```js
function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.cl').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#sumAll').val(add);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  Costos Servicios : <input id="Text1" class="cl" type="text" onChange="suma();" />
  <br />
  Costo Infraestructura : <input id="Text2" class="cl" type="text" onChange="suma();" />
  <br />
  Costo Licencias : <input id="Text3" class="cl" type="text" onChange="suma();" />
  <br />
  Total : <input id="sumAll" type="text" value="" />
  <br />
```

Otra opcion que tambien cumple el mismo funcionamiento es que dejes tu codigo tal como esta, salvo que el evento `keyup` no este dentro de una funcion sino, que este dentro del `document.ready`

Consejo :

Ahorrate `importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());` por `importe_total+= eval($(this).val());`