# Error en la implementacion de un plugin que suma todos los inputs de una clase y los devuelve en otro

Tags: html, jquery, web

Lo que busca la app es que al insertar valores en los input automaticamente genere una suma que se vea reflejado en el ultimo input, cabe aclarar que todos los inputs .currency estan vinculados a un plugin que genera una mascara de moneda... el codigo js de la mascara no lo pase porque me parecio irrelevante en este contexto.
Dicho plugin lo vi en otra publicación del foro( [sumar inputs con jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38386/sumar-inputs-con-jquery/38391#38391) ), quise aplicarlo a mi código pero no logro hacer que funcione.

```js
function calcularTotal(){
$('.currency').keyup(function() {
    var importe_total = 0
      $(".currency").each(
        function(index, value) {
          if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
          importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
          //console.log(importe_total);
          }
        }
      );
          $("#total").val(importe_total);
    });
}
```

```css
.iconos {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: grey;
} 
.iconos:hover{
    color: black;
}
.fila{
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 2px rgb(184, 184, 184);
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.formatCurrency.js"></script>
    <script src="calcularTotal.js"></script>
    <title>Calcula tu Inflacion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        calcularTotal();
    });
</script>
      <h3 class="mb-5">Calcula tu inflación</h3>
    <div class="container font-monospace">
        <form>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                            <label for="alimentos" class="form-label fs-6">Alimentos y bebidas no alcohólicas</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="alimentos" value="0,00">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center ">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="bebidas" class="form-label">Bebidas alcohólicas y tabaco</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control  form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="bebidas" value="0,00">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="prendas" class="form-label">Prendas de vestir y calzado</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="prendas" value="0,00">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="vivienda" class="form-label">Vivienda, agua, electricidad y otros combustibles</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="vivienda" value="0,00">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="equipamiento" class="form-label">Equipamiento y mantenimiento del hogar</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="equipamiento" value="0,00">                    
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                              
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="bienes" class="form-label">Bienes y servicios varios</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="bienes" value="0,00">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="alimentos" class="form-label">TOTAL</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1" id="total">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center ">
                <div class="col-8 mb-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)})
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cual es el error o problema?

Comment: al colocar los numeros en los primeros inputs no devuelve ningun valor en el input #total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando dices esto:

> ...cabe aclarar que todos los inputs .currency estan vinculados a un plugin que genera una mascara de moneda... el codigo js de la mascara no lo pase porque ***me parecio irrelevante** en este contexto*.

Resulta que sí puede ser relevante, porque en Javascript no importa cómo muestres los números, para realizar cálculos no debe haber separador de miles y los decimales siempre se separan con un punto.

Mis sugerencias:

- Usa el evento `input`, porque captura cada entrada, incluso si cortas o pegas del portapapeles
- Crea una variable adicional para obtener el valor de cada campo
- Elimina el formato de moneda para poder usar como valor numérico

  - Elimina todos los puntos (o el separador de miles que estés usando)
  - Remplaza la coma *"decimal"* por punto
- Evita el uso de [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), que puede traer más problemas que soluciones y solo necesitas una función para convertir de cadena a número, ya sea `Number()` o `parseFloat()`, pero eso ya depende de tus preferencias

Finalmente, agrega el formato deseado para mostrar el importe total.

```js
function calcularTotal() {
    // De preferencia, usa el evento input
    $('.currency').on('input', function() {
        let importe_total = 0;
        $(".currency").each(
            function(index, value) {
                // Eliminar separador de miles y convertir separador decimal de coma a punto
                let curVal = $(this).val().replaceAll('.', '').replace(',', '.');
                if($.isNumeric(curVal)) {
                    importe_total += Number(curVal);
                }
            }
        );
        // Vas a necesitar aplicar formato al total
        importe_total=importe_total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total").val(importe_total);
    });
}
```

```css
.iconos {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: grey;
} 
.iconos:hover{
    color: black;
}
.fila{
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 2px rgb(184, 184, 184);
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.formatCurrency.js"></script>
    <script src="calcularTotal.js"></script>
    <title>Calcula tu Inflacion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        calcularTotal();
    });
</script>
      <h3 class="mb-5">Calcula tu inflación</h3>
    <div class="container font-monospace">
        <form>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                            <label for="alimentos" class="form-label fs-6">Alimentos y bebidas no alcohólicas</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="alimentos" value="0,00">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center ">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="bebidas" class="form-label">Bebidas alcohólicas y tabaco</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control  form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="bebidas" value="0,00">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="prendas" class="form-label">Prendas de vestir y calzado</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="prendas" value="0,00">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="vivienda" class="form-label">Vivienda, agua, electricidad y otros combustibles</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="vivienda" value="0,00">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="equipamiento" class="form-label">Equipamiento y mantenimiento del hogar</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="equipamiento" value="0,00">                    
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                              
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="bienes" class="form-label">Bienes y servicios varios</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1 currency" id="bienes" value="0,00">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row fila">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="alimentos" class="form-label">TOTAL</label><i class="iconos bi bi-patch-question-fill mx-1" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Este es el titulo del popover" data-trigger="hover" data-bs-content="Este es el contenido de un popover"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input type="input" class="form-control form-control-sm  mt-1 mb-1" id="total">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center ">
                <div class="col-8 mb-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)})
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estuve testeando el código y he comprobado que en ocasiones el input `#total` devuelve números con varios decimales, se podría decir que no los "redondea", paso un enlace con la captura de pantalla que respalda lo que digo  https://ibb.co/X5zmC3z . He implementado esta línea de código para subsanar ese detalle `importe_total=importe_total.toFixed(2);`

Comment: Otro detalle es que cuando en los input `.currency` se tipea algún número decimal pero usando el "." como separador decimal, el código jquery lo interpreta como un entero por ende el valor devuelto por `#total` es incorrecto, claramente entiendo que esto se debe a que fue optimizado para interpretar que el separador decimal es la "," , supongo que ¿debería aplicar alguna mascara para arreglar este detalle?

Comment: @Ultimatux, de acuerdo a lo que mencionas _"todos los inputs .currency estan vinculados a un plugin que genera una mascara de moneda"_, se supone que el plugin debería resolver ese problema asignando puntos como separador de miles y comas como separador decimal. Si no, probablemente no estás usando el evento adecuado para aplicar la máscara.

Answer (score 1):

En el HTML está demás el script `$(document).ready(function()`. Esto debe estás en el archivo aparte, en `.js` donde está tu función, y éste debe encerrar tu función:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.currency').keyup(function() {
    var importe_total = 0
      $(".currency").each(
        function(index, value) {
          if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
          importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
          //console.log(importe_total);
          }
        }
      );
          $("#total").val(importe_total);
    });

});
```